# Android app internet status after oncreate()

Tags: android

I use this function isOnline() oncreate method to check if there is internet connection when the app is lunched and is working fine!

```
    public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Now i want to check the internet connection after the app is starting and  if there is no internet connection show alert!

i try to use this one but i don't know what im doing wrong.
manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<receiver android:name=".UpdateReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

activity class:

```
 public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ConnectivityManager)                                        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
              NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
              boolean isConnected = activeNetInfo != null && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();   
              if (!isConnected)  
{     
                 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
    finish();
            }
        });
    alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you showed under "activity class:" is not an activity, it's a broadcast receiver.

If you want to check the connection right after resuming your app, then call `isOnline()` in your activity's `onResume()` method and show the alert message if the network is not available. Also make sure to hide your alert message when activity goes to `onPause()` via `dialog.dismiss()`.

Example:

```
// In your activity:

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (!isOnline()) {
        // show your alert dialog here.
    }
}
```

Comment: onResume() method is executed if there is no internet connection ?

Comment: onResume() is always executed for every activity when you resume it. In this callback you can check whether the internet is available. I'll show an example in my answer.

Comment: '@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  
if(!isOnline()){ 
         AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
    finish();
            }
        });
    alertDialog.show();
            }'

Comment: Yes, that should work. Let me know if you have any issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
        @Override 
        public void onResume() { 
        super.onResume(); 
        if(!isOnline())
        { 
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create(); alertDialog.setTitle("ups..."); 
        alertDialog.setMessage("NO INTERNET CONNECTION");
 alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
    dialog.dismiss(); finish(); } }); 
        alertDialog.show(); 
        }
```

Comment: Something strange....Open app then disable wifi...alert is not showing....but if i unplug the router the alert is showing....very strange

Comment: This code will show an alert when you resume the app. If the app is already resumed, then you need to have a broadcast receiver registered for an internet connection events, like you showed in your question.